# Is it possible to plot a piece-wise function from lines?

Tags: plotting

The following code can explain my intention, although it does not work (the output is empty and no error message).

`line1 = Line[{0, 0}, {1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1}];
Plot[{line1}, {x, 0, 1}]`

I understand I can do it by define a "Piecewise" function, but I have a somewhat more complex line to plot (consisting of more than 10 segments), and it seems more easier to describe it by "Line". If I do it by "Piecewise", I have to hand-calculate the expression of each line segment.

Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: You may to use ListPlot here? ListPlot[ {pt1, pt2, ...} ] seems more appropriate. If you need something more general perhaps use Graphics[ Line[ ... ] ]

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your use of `Line` — should be:

```
  line1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1}}];
```

(You need a *list* of pairs as argument.)

Then simply:

```
  Graphics[line1, Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. So "Plot" cannot be used in this case?

Comment: `Plot` is typically used for functions, you can use `ListPlot` to plot several `{x,y}` pairs and make a line using the option `Joined->True`. There are other options as well, such as adding a line to an existing `Plot` of a function as an epilog. Which option you use depends on what your final goal is.